# Laravel iIntervention Image. Image source not readable

Tags: php, image, laravel, google-api, laravel-5.1

In my application users creating articles and adding images to it if user wont add a image, that application must search for it in google images and add that image to user article. But when i tried to get image from google. Im get this error:

```
     AbstractDecoder.php line 302:
Image source not readable
```

Controller Method:

```
 public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

            $file = Input::file('file');
            $imgTitle = $request->title;
            $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $imgTitle . '.jpg';
            $request->image_path = $imagePath;

            Article::create(array('title' => $request->title,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'image_path' => $imagePath));

            Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save($imagePath);
        } else {
//            $file = Input::file('file');
            $imgTitle = $request->title;

            $query = $imgTitle;

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=" . urlencode($query));

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

//            $file = file_get_contents($output);
            curl_close($ch);

            $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $imgTitle . '.jpg';

            $request->image_path = $imagePath;
            Article::create(array('title' => $request->title,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'image_path' => $imagePath));

            Image::make($output)->resize(300, 200)->save($imagePath);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Returns a json object with the results. If you want to get the first image url add

```
$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
if(!empty($responseData->results))
    $output = $output->responseData->results[0]->url;
else {
    die('no image found');
}
```

Comment: Now I'm get Undefined variable: output

Comment: Add the new line under the `$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));`

Comment: If get you correctly ` $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); $output = $output->responseData->results[0]->url;` Bur now Im get: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Gives error: Trying to get property of non-object on `$output = $output->responseData->results[0]->url;` line

Comment: You have to check if there are any results. You can't get information from nothing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a solution

```
else{
        $url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&rsz=1&q=' . $request->title;
        $url = file_get_contents($url);
        $file = json_decode($url);
        $file = $file->responseData->results[0]->url;
        $imgTitle = $request->title;
        $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $imgTitle . '.jpg';
        $request->image_path = $imagePath;

        Article::create(array('title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'image_path' => $imagePath));

        Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save($imagePath);
    }
```